# Remove lines between data, grouping and smoothing in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, smoothing

Here the problem:
I have to plot temporal series (9 years of **non-continuous** data). In the data frame that I am using there is a row with **N.A.** which separates **every** year. My aim is to plot this series with a smoothing line.
When I plot the temporal series, with the smooth I use this code:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,"%Y/%m/%d")
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date , y = antSO4 )) +
geom_line(color="gray40")+
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 3000)) +
scale_x_date(breaks="year", labels=date_format("%Y")) +
geom_smooth(aes(x= Date, y=antSO4), method = lm, formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = FALSE, colour = 'red')
```

I obtain this:

[image]

as you can see the are some lines which connected two different yearly series, but **not all** the series. To eliminate this problem I group the dataset by years, with:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date , group = year(Date), y = antSO4))
```

This is the plot that I obtain.

[image]

Grouping data eliminates the connections but at the same time, correctly, the smooth is calculated year per year, and not on the complete dataset.
I am quite new in the use of R, so I searched in the previous posts but I saw that many problem are connected with the presence of separation rows with N.A., and generally, the connection are between every series.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Hi Alessandra. It's impossible to test without any sample data, but you could try `ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = antSO4)) + geom_line(aes(group = year(Date))) + geom_smooth()` . This should allow grouping of the lines without the joining lines you don't want, but will smooth the data for all observations (I think that's what you're looking for?)

Comment: @AllanCameron That is exactly what I was looking for... and it works!! Thank you!!